# questions in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to answer these questions  but I couldn't and I need here

1)  List the number of days that have elapsed since each student joined.
this what I did

```
Select FR_FIRSTNAME, 
       FR_LASTNAME, 
       trunc(sysdate - FR_DATEJOINED) / 7 DAYS 
from alharbi_bandar5_FRESHMEN;
```

no rows selected

2)  List the student names and city in upper case.

This what i did

```
Select FR_FIRSTNAME, FR_LASTNAME, CITY FROM alharbi_bandar5_FRESHMEN
where UPPER (FR_FIRSTNAME, FR_LASTNAME, CITY) like 'SMITH%';

> where UPPER (FR_FIRSTNAME, FR_LASTNAME, CITY) like 'SMITH%'
*
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments
```

3)  List the no and last name of the student(s) with the highest ACT score.

This what i did

```
Select FR_NO, FR_LASTNAME, ACT from alharbi_bandar5_FRESHME
where ACT = MAX(ACT);

where ACT = MAX(ACT)
*
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
```

this is my table

```
FR_ FR_FIRSTNAME                   FR_LASTNAME                    FR_DATEJO        ACT CITY                                         
--- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ --------- ---------- ------------------------------               
100 Mark                           Ramon                          12-JUL-13         21 Florence                                     
101 John                           Wright                         13-JUN-13         31 Edgewood                                     
102 Peter                          Sellers                        06-JAN-13         30 Blue Ash                                     
103 Eric                           Bates                          14-MAY-13         24 Milford                                      
104 Theresa                        Boyers                         23-APR-13         22 Covingtion                                   
105 Alex                           William                        04-MAR-13         24 Edgewood                                     
106 Eric                           Byrd                           23-MAR-13         19 Alexandria                                   
107 Steve                          Norris                         21-DEC-12         21 Highland                             
108 Lisa                           Nkosi                          13-FEB-13         33 Florence                                     
109 Bradley                        Rego                           21-FEB-12         29 Covington                                    
110 Kathy                          Thomas                         15-OCT-12         27 Milford                                      
111 Catherine                      Jones                          17-APR-13         34 Edgewood                                     
112 Emily                          Hess                           15-NOV-12         36 Highland                             
113 Josha                          Hunter                         19-MAY-14         31 Florence
```

Comment: You serously need to study SQL first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of these questions have answers in the Oracle SQL reference and are mostly syntax issues.

1) trunc(sysdate - FR_DATEJOINED) / 7 DAYS
   Oracle gies out the number of days in the units of difference, so sysdate - FR_DATEJOINED would gie you number of days, which could also involve fractional component (2.5 days for example, if it has been 2 days and 12 hours since the candidate joined). Trunc would get rid of the fractional component, but "/7" would convert the result into number of weeks instead. why are you doing this?

Either way, i don't believe this query is being fired against the table below, otherwise you'd not get zero rows as you are not filtering anything at all.

Check these out for more info on Oracle's date functions.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/date-and-time-functions.html
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H18UWBoHhHY

2) UPPER function accepts a column name or an expression, so if you need multiple columns. you'd need to use UPPER around each column.

3) For this example, you'll need to use a subquery to get the max value first and then use the query on top.

getting the max value

```
Select max(act) from alharbi_bandar5_FRESHME;
```

so, final query would be...

```
Select FR_NO, FR_LASTNAME, ACT from alharbi_bandar5_FRESHME
where ACT = (select MAX(ACT) from alharbi_bandar5_FRESHME);
```

Or, you could use the oracle rank function..

```
select fr_no,
       fr_last_name,
       act
from   (
  select fr_no, fr_lastname, act,
         rank () over (order by act desc) rnk 
  from   alharbi_bandar5_FRESHME
) where rnk = 1
```

Comment: Isn't the last query nothing but, `SELECT ..ORDER BY ACT DESC FETCH 1 ROWS ONLY`? Or, `WHERE ROWNUM = 1` in outer query? Why to use subquery and scan the table twice? Think..

Comment: Lalit - Initially, I was only trying to get the user's query to work, based on what he was trying to implement, so I probably missed the other options. rownum <= x might be equivalent in some cases, but it is not the same query that the OP is trying to write. If multiple people have the highest ACT, the above query would give all the rows with the highest ACT, rownum <= 1 would give only one of the rows. You could use the analytic function rank() for an equivalent query. I'll add that to the answer. Thanks!